# Let a Javascript Objects doing something when user scrolls

Tags: javascript

I'm new to OOP in Javascript and I'm having some difficulties.

I wanted to manage objects that do something when they are in viewport.

### The code I used

Here is the code that I've implemented. Please note that the problem is especially on the row `window.addEventListener( 'scroll', this.i_am_watching.bind(this), false );` that does not work as expected.

```
<html><head>

    <style>
        .content { background: #f8f8f8; padding: 20px; height: 1000px; }
        .person { padding: 20px; font-size: 20px; line-height: 20px; }
        .person.mark { background: pink; }
        .person.peter { background: lightblue; }
        .person.albert { background: lightgreen; }
        div + div { margin-top: 20px; }
        div { border: 1px solid black; }
        #console { position: fixed; top: 10px; right: 10px; width: 50%; height: 300px; overflow: auto; border: 3px solid black; background: white; }
    </style>

</head><body>

    <div id="console"></div>
    <div class="content">...some content...</div>
    <div id="mark_div" class="person mark">MARK</div>
    <div class="content">...some content...</div>
    <div id="peter_div" class="person peter">PETER</div>
    <div class="content">...some content...</div>
    <div id="albert_div" class="person albert">ALBERT</div>
    <div class="content">...some content...</div>

    <script>

        function Person( name, div_id )
        {
            // properties
            this.label = name;
            this.div = document.getElementById( div_id );           

            // auxiliary function
            this.is_in_viewport = function( el )
            {
                var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
                return (
                    rect.top+el.offsetHeight >= 0 &&
                    rect.left >= 0 &&
                    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
                    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
                );
            }

            // i_am_watching
            this.i_am_watching = function()
            {
                if( this.is_in_viewport( this.div ) ) document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "I'm watching <b>"+name+"<br>" ;
            }

            // listener
            window.addEventListener( 'scroll', this.i_am_watching, false );
        }

        Person( "mark", "mark_div" );
        Person( "peter", "peter_div" );
        Person( "albert", "albert_div" );

    </script>

</body></html>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bd3182zw/2/

### The problem

The problem is that the listener fires only and always when Albert is on the viewport. And when it fires, all objects execute the `i_am_watching` method.

### `bind` doesn't work

As suggested in the [MDN reference for EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler) (section "The value of this within the handler"), I've tried to add `.bind(this)` after the function called by the listener, in order to ensure that `this` applies to the right object; but as you can see,m it doesn't work.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *"`bind` doesn't work"* You do definitely need the `bind` in that line (or [one of the other solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)). That doesn't mean there isn't a *different* problem *as well*. Presumably the calculation in `is_in_viewport` isn't quite right (when you do have the `bind` so it gets called). Your best bet for figuring that out is to debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in `Person` function is `window` the global object when acalled like this.

To instanciate a class object, please create it with a `new` operator.

```
    new Person( "mark", "mark_div" );
    new Person( "peter", "peter_div" );
    new Person( "albert", "albert_div" );
```

Then the `Person` has his own context.

PS: Don't forget your binding !

```
        // listener
        window.addEventListener( 'scroll', this.i_am_watching.bind( this ), false );
```

Comment: Here is the logical piece I missed! thank you, it worked.